# Is my database in an elastic pool?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am trying to set up an Azure SQL Database inside of an elastic pool. I'm not sure if I did it right.  Here's my dashboard:

[image]

And here's the actual database:

[image]

What makes me wonder if the database is actually inside the elastic pool is what's circled in red in the above screenshot.

> No elastic pool

Here's the server:

[image]

And here's the elastic pool:

[image]

Another clue that the DB is not in the pool is that the pool shows no usage.

So, I'm pretty sure I did something wrong. But I can't seem to figure out HOW to put the database inside the pool.

Help!?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure: How to move databases into Elastic Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351426/azure-how-to-move-databases-into-elastic-pool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add database to elastic pool as long as they are on the same logical server. [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool#manage-elastic-pools-and-databases-using-the-azure-portal) the article. Search for "Move a database into an elastic pool". I cannot really copy text from there to here as there is no text, only a bunch of images.

Comment: btw, there also are ways to do that with powershell\cli\t-sql